# calling parent implementations of privileged functions

Tags: javascript, oop

I have an inheritance relationship between two JavaScript classes<sup>1</sup>

```
RealTimeChart = function(chartAttributes) {

    var chart = new FusionCharts(chartAttributes);

    this.appendData = function(data) {
        chart.feedData(data);
    }
};

RealTimeGauge = function(chartAttributes) {
    chartAttributes.type = 'AngularGauge';

    // call parent constructor
    RealTimeChart.call(this, chartAttributes);
};

// inherit from RealTimeChart
RealTimeGauge.prototype = Object.create(RealTimeChart.prototype);
```

In `RealTimeGauge` I would like to override `appendData()`. The implementation of this function in `RealTimeGauge` needs to call the parent implementation, is this possible?

It's relatively straightforward to do this if I change `appendData` to a prototype function, e.g.

```
// parent class
RealTimeChart.prototype.appendData = function(data) {
    this.chart.feedData(data);
};

// child class
RealTimeGauge.prototype.appendData = function(data) {

    console.log("doing custom stuff...");

    // call the parent function to add the data to the chart
    RealTimeChart.prototype.appendData.call(this, data);
};
```

However, if I make `appendData` a prototype function rather than a privileged function, I also have to make `chart` a public property, which I'd rather not do. Is it possible to call the parent implementation of `appendData` form `RealTimeGauge` if it's a privileged function?

1. I know they're not really classes, but I don't know of a better name for them

Comment: After calling the superconstructor, doesn't `this` have `appendData` as own property?

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn it does, which is why it's not obvious how to provide an implementation of `appendData` in the subclass that call's the parent's implementation I suspect it is not possible

Comment: I still don't get the problem, let me try a short example / edit: done, if I understood correctly, the answer below should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the child constructor, after the calling the super constructor, `this` holds the priviledged function as an own property.

You can reassign this to a temporary variable and create the wrapping function that will replace super's implementation:

```
Parent = function() {
    var x = 1;

    this.work = function(y) {
        console.log(x + y);
    }
};

Child = function() {
    Parent.call(this);

    var super_work = this.work

    this.work = function(y) {
        super_work(y + 10); 
    }
};

Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype);
```

Let's give it a try:

```
p = new Parent()
p.work(1) # prints 2

c = new Child()
c.work(1) # prints 12
```

Comment: True, fixed it. I usually write CoffeeScript :P

Answer (score -1):

To avoid this issue altogether, you could drop inheritance, and go for composition.

```
RealTimeChart = function(chartAttributes) {
    var chart = new FusionCharts(chartAttributes);
    this.appendData = function(data) {
        chart.feedData(data);
    };
};

RealTimeGauge = function (realTimeChart) {
    this.appendData = function (data) {
        console.log("doing custom stuff...");
        realTimeChart.appendData(data);
    };
};

new RealTimeGauge(new RealTimeChart({}));
```

[Using composition results in simpler, more modular code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance#Benefits). As you can see in the above code, `RealTimeGauge` only depends on the interface of `RealTimeChart`, not `RealTimeChart` itself, like in your original code. This means that you can substitute anything that has the same interface. The 2 'classes' are now decoupled. At what price? Less code that's more readable. You could go even further and decouple `RealTimeChart` from `FusionCharts` in the same way.

Comment: Side note: this answer stands for all languages, not only JavaScript.